# Cannot open the url

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I am using chrome driver..

util

```
package util;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class DriverManager {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl="http://qmsadm.local";

    public DriverManager()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","pathToGeckodriver");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

Console error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session   (Driver
>   info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64)
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 84 milliseconds Build info: version:
>   '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700' System
>   info: host: 'naveen-Inspiron-3542', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-47-generic', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_111' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{message=unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision:
>   ed651c97177b2ac846b27f62bb8efed6dac0f90b   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64),
>   platform=ANY}] Session ID: c377f4dfc8dbecfa033afa8b8b90995a
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
>     at util.DriverManager.(DriverManager.java:19)     at
>   client.clientTest.initDriver(clientTest.java:18)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:143)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:307)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)   at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>
> Test ignored.
>   =============================================== Default Suite Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1 Configuration Failures: 1, Skips:
>
> ## 1

Comment: Please just do not copy paste code. Understand the configuration changes also. It would save your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

download chrome driver from  this link https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/ and write as below code:

```
public  static void setup(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium \\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

it is working for me

Comment: Good answer but it is for windows. @AntonyNaveen can you please confirm it is Linux based system. As per your question stack trace.

Comment: Sorry i dont hav eany idea for linux .but you can check https://techarena51.com/index.php/install-selenium-linux-automate-web-tests/ this link

Comment: Rutvi , Your answer is absolutely correct for windows. I have already given answer based on Linux and it was corrected first. But I do not understand why @AntonyNaveen had changed. So I am confused about this action.

Comment: @Sagar007 what's the problem? Simply download the Linux version of chromedriver and point it to your correct path (which you will have to do anyway, unless you want to create Selenium folder on your E: drive")

Comment: @lostInCode Please try to understand problem. Question is about to solve on another OS. Each OS has different folder structure. Please refer : https://www.howtogeek.com/137096/6-ways-the-linux-file-system-is-different-from-the-windows-file-system/

Comment: @Sagar007 I understand the problem perfectly. What I am saying is that anyone competent enough to do testing/QA knows this. Thus providing flle paths for every possible system out there is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid driver config issues in the future you can use WebdriverManager. read full info here: 
https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

you can replace the line

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","pathToGeckodriver");
```

with `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();` this is platform independent and will download the corresponding web driver binaries so you can leave out the configuration step in the future

you will need to import the `WebDriverManger` dependency

Assuming you are using maven in your project.
add the following dependency within the parent `<dependencies></dependencies>` tags   to your pom.xml file,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
<artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code replace **pathToGeckodriver** with the actual path of the Chrome Driver exe.

Your code needs to find the Chrome Driver for it to be able to integrate and execute Chrome Driver's bit.

The path should be something like **c:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe** meaning the path to the exe file for Chrome Driver. If not sure just open the folder where you have placed the chromedriver.exe file on your computer, copy the path in the explorer's address bar and append the exe file's name to it when you paste it in your code.

For Ubuntu or any other Linux based system, you can find the path to the chromedriver shell script file and use that path without the **.exe** extension. It should be something like **home/antony/chromedriver** or the path whatever folder you have the chromedriver shell script file in.

You can download the Chrome Driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).

Comment: I am using ubuntu os  I put this  System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "home/naveen/chromedriver");    But still same error came..

Answer (score 0):

Please update chrome browser and download latest chromedriver from [Download](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) link

Extract the zip file

Put downloaded `chromedriver` at path `/home/naveen/`

For chrome driver use this `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/naveen/chromedriver");`

Comment: i did same issue happens

Comment: @user21268 Did the right answer solve issue ?